# What is the best way to make an asynchronous push to an external web service from a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When a user posts a comment to my Rails application, I want the comment to be pushed to an external web service. This external web service could be slow, so I want to make this push asynchronously. I am not interested in the response from the web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to use a task queue and background worker.

Take a look at [Sidekiq](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/), for example. Or [BackgroundJob](http://codeforpeople.rubyforge.org/svn/bj/trunk/README). Or [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque).

Basically, in your rails app you say "I want this be called in background" and put a task to a queue (backed by [redis](/questions/tagged/redis)/[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)/[erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang)/whatever). Then another process (background worker) retrieves tasks from the queue and executes them.

For a quick-and-dirty solution you can use threads:

```
Thread.new do
  # this stuff will be executed asynchronously
end
```

But this is only suitable for very small apps. Do not try this under heavy load.

Comment: Thanks. I am already experimenting with Resque. But if i spawn a thread, won't it get killed when the request that spawned it ends?

Comment: Usually rails is served by a long-running process. This means that process (and its threads) far outlive any individual request.

Comment: Ok. I am going with Resque.